# Use Django Rest API From Any Origin

Tags: django, rest, authentication, csrf, rest-client

I have a REST API implemented using Django DRF.

My API is working just fine when used from `my-domain.com`, however I would like the API to be accessible from any origin.

I have implemented CORS/CSRF using the following configuration:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME="XSRF-TOKEN"
CSRF_HEADER_NAME="HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN"
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = (
    'my-domain.com'    # I have tried adding my ip address here, but no luck
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-xsrf-token',
    'x-requested-with',
    'Api-Key'
)
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = (
    'Set-Cookie',
)
```

When I make a request to `my-domain.com/api/` from `my-domain.cm` I get the expected header:

```
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=csmi.........................DK7; expires=Wed, 26 Aug 2020 11:43:51 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

When I make a request to `my-domain.com/api/` from my personal computer or from a 3rd REST API testing site, I do not get the expected header.

I would like my API to be accessible from any ip address. How do I configure my settings?

*To further elaborate, I am attempting to login to `my-domain.com/api/auth/` using a post request with my credentials. I am getting a 405 error, and I believe it is because I am no sending the xsrf-token in my headers. I am making an initial get request to get the xsrf token but I am not receiving it in the headers.*

Comment: CSRF token has nothing to do with CORS. CORS tells a browser whether or not it should accept responses when making javascript request. CSRF is way to check the integrity of a form and to prevent replay requests (e.g. a 3rd party submitting a form on your behalf without your consent). If you're building an API that should be accessible on any website, your CORS headers are fine. But you should disable CSRF for the views that will be accessed by 3rd parties since they cannot receive the CSRF token in the first place. Add the @csrf_exempt decorator to your views.

Comment: Note that if your API is not consumed in a browser, but from other servers, CORS doesn't matter.

Comment: Thats not how you authenticate users on an API, use token or smething. Look at [drf docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).

Comment: @VaibhavVishal it is, the user needs to authenticate the first time somehow, that's normally done with a username/password (after which the Authentication header is used to send the token). Otherwise how do you create the user token in the first place?

Comment: yes, but that endpoint doesn't needs any csrf token.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Use csrf_exempt.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a few things here:

- CORS is a standard protocol to let browsers know what they should accept and what not. Basically, if any request is made on a webpage (e.g. a script, but it can also be the HTML document that needs to fetch images, scripts etc...), the server that responds to that request can indicate using CORS which webpages are allowed to consume the response. By default, browsers don't allow any responses from domains that don't match the domain of the current web page.

  So in your case, if your API is intended to be consumed from 3rd party webpages, then you need to set the CORS headers to allow these 3rd parties. In your case, your settings are correct.

  Note that if your API is supposed to be consumed by other servers (not from within a browser), then the CORS headers don't apply, but you could remove them to disallow consumption from within webpages.
- CSRF tokens are a way to verify the integrity of the data that is being submitted via POST requests. It allows you to ascertain that the POST data comes from a `<form>` that you rendered. It makes it difficult for hidden 3rd party scripts to submit data to your server using a user's existing session, since the 3rd party cannot create a CSRF-token to submit as POST parameter that matches the CSRF cookie in the user's session.

  If you want 3rd parties to use your API without having to fetch a form first, you should make all the views of your API csrf exempt using the [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator. Do not, **I repeat, do not** offer an API to fetch the CSRF token, since that opens up the vulnerability mentioned above.

  If you want to protect your API from being used only by approved 3rd parties, you have other methods: Give them a (secret) API key, making sure you only accept requests over secure HTTP (TLS), or check the origin of requests with IP addresses.